# How to make an Event registration form where you can choose which event you are registering for?

Tags: civievent, profile, forms, civicrm-home

Let's say I want to make 3 Webinars, I want a registration form where people can enter their contact info and then select the Webinar (which is an event) and than click submit. I can do it with custom fields and bypass the events altogether but I want to define a maximum number of participants and automatically close the registration for a particular Webinar once the number has been reached.

Is this doable?

Comment: Are you on Drupal or Backdrop? If so you I believe you can do it using webform_civicrm in the Event Registration > Registration Options section.

Comment: This is a Drupal-only solution: http://civiteacher.com/video/how-register-multiple-events-webform

Comment: @Coleman I would upvote that answer if you left it as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Price Set (used for Event) with a Price Field for each Webinar (Input Field checkbox). You can set a Participate Count and Max Participants for each Price Field. When you create your event, under the Fees Tab, Enter the Price Set name. You can charge a different amount for each webinar or $0 for all of them.  I know this does not create 3 separate events in your reports, but it does give you the ability to automatically close registration when full. You can filter your reports by Price set boxes.